# Snowflake ETL Job Using PySpark Works on Local But Not on Dataproc

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

I created a spark job and I've tested it on local first, to which it worked flawlessly. However, after passing the spark job to Dataproc, it returns the following error:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o78.load.
: net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeSQLException: Private key provided is invalid or not supported: Please use java.security.interfaces.RSAPrivateCrtKey.class
```

**Pyspark Code**

```
sfOptions = ConnectToSnowflake(creds_path='creds.json').get_spark_sf_creds()

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .config("spark.jars", "jars/snowflake-jdbc-3.8.0.jar,jars/spark-snowflake_2.11-2.4.13-spark_2.4.jar") \
    .config("spark.repl.local.jars",
            "jars/snowflake-jdbc-3.8.0.jar,jars/spark-snowflake_2.11-2.4.13-spark_2.4.jar") \
    .config("spark.sql.catalogImplementation", "in-memory") \
    .getOrCreate()

spark._jvm.net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.SnowflakeConnectorUtils.enablePushdownSession(
    spark._jvm.org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate())

snowflake_source_name = 'net.snowflake.spark.snowflake'

df = spark.read.format(snowflake_source_name) \
    .options(**sfOptions) \
    .option("query", query) \
    .load()

df.show()
```

**Dataproc**

```sh
gcloud dataproc jobs submit pyspark --cluster featurelib-cluster \
    --jars gs://dataproc-featurelib/spark-lib/snowflake-jdbc-3.8.0.jar,gs://dataproc-featurelib/spark-lib/spark-snowflake_2.11-2.4.13-spark_2.4.jar \
    --py-files snowflake_connector.py \
    --files creds.json,daodl_access.json \
    sf_loader.py
```

**Full Stack Trace of Error**

```
net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeSQLException: Private key provided is invalid or not supported: Please use java.security.interfaces.RSAPrivateCrtKey.class
        at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeConnectionV1.<init>(SnowflakeConnectionV1.java:136)
        at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeDriver.connect(SnowflakeDriver.java:148)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
        at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.JDBCWrapper.getConnector(SnowflakeJDBCWrapper.scala:180)
        at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.SnowflakeRelation$$anonfun$schema$1.apply(SnowflakeRelation.scala:56)
        at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.SnowflakeRelation$$anonfun$schema$1.apply(SnowflakeRelation.scala:53)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
        at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.SnowflakeRelation.schema$lzycompute(SnowflakeRelation.scala:53)
        at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.SnowflakeRelation.schema(SnowflakeRelation.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:403)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:223)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:167)
        at $line17.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:28)
        at $line17.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:33)
        at $line17.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:35)
        at $line17.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:37)
        at $line17.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:39)
        at $line17.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:41)
        at $line17.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:43)
        at $line17.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:45)
        at $line17.$read$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:47)
        at $line17.$read$$iw.<init>(<console>:49)
        at $line17.$read.<init>(<console>:51)
        at $line17.$read$.<init>(<console>:55)
        at $line17.$read$.<clinit>(<console>)
        at $line17.$eval$.$print$lzycompute(<console>:7)
        at $line17.$eval$.$print(<console>:6)
        at $line17.$eval.$print(<console>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:793)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:1054)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:645)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:644)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:31)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.AbstractFileClassLoader.asContext(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:19)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest.loadAndRunReq(IMain.scala:644)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:576)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:572)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.interpretStartingWith(ILoop.scala:819)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.command(ILoop.scala:691)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.processLine(ILoop.scala:404)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.loop(ILoop.scala:425)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:285)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.runClosure(SparkILoop.scala:159)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:182)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.doMain(Main.scala:78)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:58)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:845)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:161)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:184)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:86)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:920)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:929)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

Comment: I think there's a bug in the jar files. I recreated the code in scala in Spark Shell and it returned the same error. Although, that doesn't really explain why it would work on local and not on Dataproc

Comment: It feels like you have some SF related keys/configs on local, did you configure it the same way in Dataproc?

Comment: @RileyHun Is this issue fixed. If yes, what was the fix. Please update.

Answer (score 0):

To pass the `creds.json` key you should use `--jars` flag instead of `--files` flag (this way it will be added to classpath):

```sh
gcloud dataproc jobs submit pyspark --cluster featurelib-cluster \
    --jars gs://dataproc-featurelib/spark-lib/snowflake-jdbc-3.8.0.jar,gs://dataproc-featurelib/spark-lib/spark-snowflake_2.11-2.4.13-spark_2.4.jar,creds.json \
    --py-files snowflake_connector.py \
    --files daodl_access.json \
    sf_loader.py
```

If it doesn't work, try to upgrade Snowflake jars to the latest versions.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding the `Bouncy Castle` security provider in the first position.

In the Dataproc image(in my case `2.0.77-debian10`) `Conscrypt version 1.0` is being used as a first Security provider and, I am not sure why, but `Bouncy Castle` is missing from providers at all.

My local security providers are(`Security.getProviders()`):
`SUN version 1.8, SunRsaSign version 1.8, SunEC version 1.8, SunJSSE version 1.8, SunJCE version 1.8, SunJGSS version 1.8, SunSASL version 1.8, XMLDSig version 1.8, SunPCSC version 1.8, Apple version 1.8, BC version 1.7`

But on a cluster, they are:
`Conscrypt version 1.0, SUN version 1.8, SunRsaSign version 1.8, SunEC version 1.8, SunJSSE version 1.8, SunJCE version 1.8, SunJGSS version 1.8, SunSASL version 1.8, XMLDSig version 1.8, SunPCSC version 1.8`.

I tried to remove it first and received a different error code:
`Unsupported CipherSuite: TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256  at sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite.validValuesOf(CipherSuite.java:995)`

Snowflake spark connector uses Bouncy Castle as a security provider, so in order to fix this issue, I tried to place it in the first place and everything started working(java code):
`Security.insertProviderAt(new BouncyCastleProvider(), 1);`